# A confusion on the figure `Connected TCP sockets` in book 'The Linux Programming Interface'

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel

I am not sure if the `send buffer` and `receive buffer` for `Application B` in the following screenshot need to be swapped.

The screenshot is captured from *The Linux Programming Interface*, section 58.6.3

[image]

Comment: You are correct. The diagram is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `send buffer` and `receive buffer` for Application B should to be swapped